# youtube Received error rendering template: Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=258

Tags: ios, objective-c, youtube, cocoapods

I try

```
[self.playerView loadWithVideoId:@"M7lc1UVf-VE"];
```

but `self.playerView` not `response` and `error`

```
youtube[14628:2831405] Received error rendering template: Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=258 "The file name is invalid."
```

what wrong?

Comment: The error happens to me intermittently and when the application loads the video it become very slow with lag

Answer (score 17):

I had the same issue. I used CocoaPods and for some reason the `Assets` folder was not installed.

A work around would be to manually add the `Assets.bundle` folder - the guide is pretty straight forward about that. I am sure you have already checked it :)
  https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/guides/ios_youtube_helper

Then I ran the `pod install` command once again and it worked just fine.

Comment: Thank you very much :D , but now i pod XCDYoutubeKit. it's work for me! https://github.com/0xced/XCDYouTubeKit

Comment: Beware, I used that library for a few months and it has some issues with VEVO clips. Check the issues - there are 5-6 issues about this from yesterday. It is a tower in the sand ;)

Comment: Seeking clarification: Did you keep your cocoapods installation and manually add Assets.bundle to it somehow or did you just do a full manual addition of the library?

Comment: @Newtz I installed the library via ``cocoapods``. Then I manually added the bundle and then run ``pod install`` once again

Comment: @Mikhail Where does the bundle need to be manually added for it to work? I don't know the inner workings of libraries very well

Comment: @Newtz after running the ```pod install``` you should have a folder for the YT library. You should place the ```bundle``` folder inside it.

Answer (score 6):

I ran into the same issue as well.
I found a solution that works for me on their Github page:
https://github.com/youtube/youtube-ios-player-helper/issues/160

Specifically, I just changed the pod with the following:

`pod 'youtube-ios-player-helper', :git=>'https://github.com/youtube/youtube-ios-player-helper', :commit=>'head'`

hope that helps

Comment: I hope they update their library soon. It seems to be having a lot of issues compared to XCDYoutubeKit...

Answer (score 5):

Alternate way / In case of manual installation

- right click on Assets.bundle
- show package contents
- open Assets folder
- select **YTPlayerView-iframe-player.html** file and add to your project folder. Done !

Comment: Actually, you have to drag the Assets folder into Xcode, check "Copy items if needed", and select "Create folder references".

Answer (score 2):

Make sure `YTPlayerView-iframe-player.html` is copied into your Xcode project and it appears in Settings -> Build Settings -> Copy Bundle Resources.